# KNIME: how can I read/get a node name (which was manually written) with another node?

Tags: logging, knime, nodename

I have put names in each of my nodes. Now I want to create a custom log including my custom names for nodes.

I need to read or get the name of the node with another node/variable/other.

How can I get this done?

Comment: There is no API to get the node's name. You might consider adding nodes input some properties in one of its columns, and use that information instead of the node name. (In case you are interested I have created some nodes to add these kind of roles for columns, though I understand this is not what you want, so not linking here.)

Comment: @GáborBakos thanks! can you share an example of nodes you created? I tried adding an empty table and then start to add rows each time I execute some main nodes, but it gets too complicated and heavy, having "logger" nodes around the whole workflow.

Comment: Sure, here are the nodes for handling the properties: https://github.com/aborg0/com.mind_era.knime.roles, though those are also part of the trunk version of RapidMiner integration (which is not automatically building currently in the community contributions). As
I understand you are attempting to create some recursive node, I think only Iris has real example for that, I cannot help. I am sure she will be happy to help answer any related questions on the KNIME forum.